# How do I get my Wifi Network Adapter to work on my MacBook Air from Early 2015?

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, macbook

As the title says I'm trying to get my WiFi to work. I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 on a MacBook Air from early 2015. It has an i5 processor, 4 GB of RAM, 128 GB Hard Disk, and a "*03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)*" network adapter. I tried the Additional Drivers App and turning the proprietary driver on and off doesn't change things. In Settings it says, "No WiFi Adapter Found. Make sure you have a WiFi adapter plugged in and turned on." The information I got about my adapter mentioned from above came from the terminal command "**lspci -nn | grep Network**" (I'm new to this sight as well as to Linux so I'm not sure on formatting). Anyway, most of what I can find on this sight either talks about different generations of MacBook or they talk about older versions of Ubuntu. I'm hopeful to get the network adapter working.

Comment: no-repro - "I ended up changing to Manjaro Linux, and it fixed my problems."

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing to Manjaro Linux, and it fixed my problems. If someone has a possible solution they would like to reply with to fix other people's issues from other times they can do so (if the forum keeps this open).