# Wifi network adaptor tips do not work on Macbook Air with Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, broadcom, macbook, 23.04

I have Ubuntu 23.04 on a MacBook Air from early 2015. The wifi adaptor is not recognized. The Macbook air has an i7 processor, 8 GB of RAM, 500 GB Hard Disk, and a Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03). Would appreciate help!

I tried the instructions on [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) but this was for an older Ubuntu version. Did not work on Ubuntu 23.04.

I looked at [How do I get my Wifi Network Adapter to work on my MacBook Air from Early 2015?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475434/how-do-i-get-my-wifi-network-adapter-to-work-on-my-macbook-air-from-early-2015) but there was no anwer.

When I checked software & Updates > extra drivers  there was selected: "dkms source for the Broadcom STA wireless driver of broadcom-sta-dkms gebruiken (niet-vrij)" (Dutch for: use ....(not free)
I tried to deselect and than again select. Wifi still did not work